# AWS SES: AccessDenied when calling SendRawEmail - User is not authorised to perform ses:SendRawEmail on Resource

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send an email via SES, I'm already out of sandbox mode. Whenever I log in on AWS and try to send an email via the 'Send test Email' button, everything works fine.
If I use Boto3/django-ses library, I get the Permission Denied error, same user, a different way of performing the action.

The user has the following policies attached:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and:

```json
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ses:SendEmail",
                "ses:SendRawEmail"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

I also attached an Authorization policy to the SES verified identity:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "stmt1682154101077",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::FOO:user/BAR"
            },
            "Action": [
                "ses:SendEmail",
                "ses:SendRawEmail"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ses:eu-central-1:FOO:identity/no-reply@example.com",
            "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Which part am I missing to give the user permission to send emails via the Library?

Comment: Are you sure, if you are using the right credentials?

Comment: @ArpitJain petty sure I'm using the correct credentials. The error messages states:
`arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:user/<my_user_name>`

I've just recreated a new set of access keys but the error message stays the same...